# Using a form submit button to go to an external link with two inputs in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm very new to MVC and I'm not sure quite how the forms work. Here's what i want to do:
[image]

So I've got two text boxes and an enter button in a form I want to put two values into the textboxes and use them in my external link. Here's the code I am trying to use, i know it's not correct at all  but should show you what I'm trying to do:

View:

```
@model Test.Models.Home
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Main";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("GetMessage()", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("Location1: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location1)
    @Html.Label("Location2: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location2)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location2)
    <button type="submit">Enter</button>
}
```

Controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using BBWebApp.Models;

namespace Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Main()
        {
            //var name = new Home() { Name = "Google maps API" };
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Location(Home model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //TODO: SubscribeUser(model.Email);
            }

            return View("Main", model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetMessage()
        {
            return Redirect("https://example.com/" + Location1 + "/" + Location2);
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class Home
    {
        public string Location1 { get; set; }
        public string Location2 { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see I'm trying to get the form to trigger the redirect function under getMessage() but obviously this code is flawed as I don't fully understand how it works. As i said I'm very new to MVC so any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you remove the parenthesis from GetMessage in @using (Html.BeginForm("GetMessage()", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) does it work?

Comment: Shouldn't `GetMessage()` have parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is very good for starting. Only have some minor problems:

On your view's `using` block, remove paranthesis from action method 
`GetMessages`

like that

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetMessage", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Label("Location1: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location1)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location1)
    @Html.Label("Location2: ")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Location2)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Location2)
    <button type="submit">Enter</button>
{
```

Then you need to get your model and use variables on your controller's method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetMessage(Home model)
{
    return Redirect("https://example.com/" + model.Location1 + "/" + model.Location2);
}
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: Perfect!! Thankyou very much I was pretty close in the first place then!